# Largest known positive integer n such that $\binom{n}{k}$ has k prime factors (counted with multiplicity) for each $k\le32$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, prime-factorization

The numbers n such that $\binom{n}{1}$ have $1$ prime factor (counted with multiplicity) are simply the primes. Therefore, for $k=1$ this gives the largest known prime, $n=2^{82589933}-1$. For $k=2$, the numbers n such that $\binom{n}{2}$ have $2$ prime factors (counted with multiplicity) are $2p$ such that $p$ and $2p-1$ are primes and the safe primes, primes $p$ such that $(p-1)/2$ is also prime. Since $2618163402417\cdot2^{1290001}-1$, the largest known prime $p$ such that $(p-1)/2$ is also prime, is greater than $7775705415\cdot2^{175116}+2=2p$, where $p$ is the largest known prime such that $2p-1$ is also prime, $2618163402417\cdot2^{1290001}-1$ is the largest known such $n$ for $k=2$. This will change from time to time.

What about $3\le k \le 32$?

For $3\le k\le 14$, I found in OEIS that $\binom{2918756139031688155200+k}{k}$, where $n=2918756139031688155200+k$, $k\le 14$, and $\binom{7272877497848202239}{k}$, where $n=7272877497848202239$, $k\le 14$, have k prime factors (counted with multiplicity). These are just the lower bounds for such $n$'s. Definitely these aren't the largest known $n$'s such that $\binom{n}{k}$ has $k$ prime factors (counted with multiplicity) for $3\le k \le6$.

**Main problem:** Find at least one positive integer $n\gt10^4$ such that $\binom{n}{k}$ has exactly $k$ prime factors (counting multiplicity) for each $15\le k\le 32$.

Comment: Not sure why this is down- and closevoted. It is surely interesting (+1). However, I am not sure whether the actual records can be found with the sources as the cases you mentioned. Are you content with huge examples to begin with ? Or do you actually want to have the current world records ?

Comment: For $k=32$ , the largest $n$ I found so far is $4793$

Comment: But for $k=5$, the largest such $n$ up to $1000004$ is $999437$. Up to $1000004$, there are $79$ such $n$'s. However, up to $100004$ there are only $31$ such $n$'s, the largest of which is $89087$. This is an evidence that there are eventually infinitely many such $n$'s, but the question asks only about the largest such $n$ (as on 2022).

Comment: I searched Wikipedia for $k=1$ and $k=2$. Try to search other sites for $3\le k\le32$.

Comment: I could post the largest cases upto $n=3\cdot 10^5$ , if that helps. For small $k$, they are surely much too small however.

Comment: The corresponding $n$'s will be indeed small for $n\le14$, since Peter is going to search only for $n\le3\cdot10^5$; try $\binom{2918756139031688155200+k}{k}$, where $n=2918756139031688155200+k$, $k\le 14$, or $\binom{7272877497848202239}{k}$, where $n=7272877497848202239$, $k\le 14$.

Comment: Where are the Peter's solutions (the largest cases for $n\le3\cdot10^5$)?

Comment: Considering the edit, I now doubt whether the table would be actually useful. Does the OEIS - link mean that someone had the same idea already , or does it just help to find huge examples for your problem ? Maybe, you work this out. Are you nevertheless still interested in the $3\cdot 10^5$-table ? Shall I post it as a partial answer ?

Comment: Yes, I'm still interested in the $3\cdot10^5$ table. You shall post it as a partial answer.

Comment: I actually want to have the current world records.

Comment: For $k=3$ , a large example is $$n=10^{99}+10280563$$ ($n$ , $\frac{n-1}{2}$ and $\frac{n-2}{3}$ are proven primes) , hence the last such known example must be huge.

Comment: For $k=12$, the only further example up to $10^{12}+11$ is $n=1676641693$. The next example in the case $k=12$ is $n=1852069955839$. For $k=2$, a large example is $n=3^{541}-1$ ($n/2$ and $n-1$ are both prime).

Comment: I now understood how huge examples can be found, but I do not know where the largest known such primes (what ever is meant with "known") can be found.

Comment: The key is the research for the mathematical records related to the number of prime factors in the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: $$n=10^{499}+36112279$$ is an even larger example for $k=3$

Comment: For $k=4$ , an example is $$n=10^{99}+3002166319$$ hence the largest known case must be still very large.

Comment: What did you find in OEiS? Can you post a link to your findings?

Comment: Please see https://oeis.org/A093553,  https://oeis.org/A093554 and possibly  https://oeis.org/A071373.

Comment: Both $\binom{924328299}{15}$ and $\binom{2537185195}{15}$ are the squarefree product of $15$ primes greater than $1000000$ without their respective factors $72$ and $216$. I want a single example where $\binom{n}{15}$ is a $15$-almost prime such that the interval $[n-14, n]$ contains $m$ primes for each integer $m$ in the interval $[0,5]$.

Comment: I thought to have $n\gt799$ to give the examples for the previous comment.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4609707/82961)

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer. As above mentioned, those values are probably much too small. The table (created with the free calculator PARI/GP) lists the largest solution $n\le 3\cdot 10^5$ for $k=3,\cdots ,32$ :

```
gp > for(k=3,32,maxi=0;for(m=k,3*10^5,s=binomial(m,k);if(bigomega(s)==k,maxi=m));print(k,"  ",maxi))
3  299723
4  298204
5  280223
6  280223
7  280223
8  280223
9  2089
10  362
11  319
12  797
13  797
14  719
15  799
16  1241
17  593
18  2099
19  2399
20  1052
21  2103
22  2974
23  2399
24  1403
25  2239
26  2106
27  5179
28  3548
29  3229
30  5182
31  5183
32  4793
gp >
```

For small $k$ , we can find at least lower bounds for the desired values. Define $n(k)$ to be the largest known $n$ for the corresponding $k$ , we can say $$n(3)\ge 10^{1000}+1401064021050844540399$$ $$n(4)\ge 10^{200}+6985786741233199$$ $$n(5)\ge lcm([1..200])\cdot 5012200-1$$ $$n(6)\ge lcm([1..200])\cdot 5012200-1$$ $$n(7)\ge lcm([1..80])\cdot 15688070-1$$ $$n(8)\ge lcm([1..80])\cdot 15688070-1$$ $$n(9)\ge lcm([1..35])\cdot 160479169-1$$ $$n(10)\ge 101114034374873519$$ With increasing $k$ , it will become more and more difficult to find huge examples. Everyone finding larger examples can edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The largest solutions appeared as close to $300000$ for small $k$, but for larger $k$, they became small for $k\gt9$, approximately $c(k)\cdot k^e$ for some function $c(k)=k^{o(1)}$. Why did this happen?

Comment: Exaclty that is what I wondered as well. Can we reformulate the requirement in terms of prime tuples ? Would that explain the break ?

Comment: Yes, it would. Use the conjecture that the sum of the prime factors (counted with multiplicity) of $\binom{n}{k}$ is at least $k\cdot log(log(n)-log(k))-(2+o(1))(log(n))$ as the positive integers $n$ and $k\ge n$ both vary.

Comment: Someone other can complete the answer to this question if he/she knows.

Comment: Can you give all the solutions to $k=9$ up to $n=2089$ and analyze them using the forms of $9$ consecutive integers, the largest of which is $n$, together with the factorization of $\binom{n}{k}$? Start with the smallest n and analyze them as the form $d\cdot${admissible product of primes} where d is the largest common divisor of the number to analyze and admissible multiple of $LCM(1..n)$ in the answer. For example, the smallest solution is $n=28$ for $k=9$ and the consecutive integers are $20$, $21$, $2p$, $p$, $24$, $5p$, $2p$, $9p$, $28$ (where p can have different values).

Comment: For example, for $\binom{142}{7}$ we have $8p$, $p$, $6p$, $p$, $140$, $3p$, $2p$ since $140k-4$ is divisible by $8$ for all integers $k$ assuming $GPF(k)\gt7$, and the multiple $8$ of $GCD(136,420)=4$ is the smallest admissible. So $8p$ can't replace $4p1p2$. And I found an error in the previous comment, "$n$" instead of "n" was recommended.

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{81777343}{10}$ has no prime factors less than $1298053$ and it is the squarefree product of $10$ primes since $1298053^2=1684941590809\gt81777343\gt LCM(1..10)+10−1=2520+10−1=2530−1=2529$.

Comment: It is difficult to find large examples from about $k=10$ on. As I said , everyone is invited to edit my answer who found a (significantly) larger example than the given one. An example for $k=8$ (and all smaller $k$) is the $42$ digit number $k=lcm([1..80])\cdot 15688070-1$

Comment: Can you find any more examples for $15\le k\le32$?

Comment: Although I tried various approaches , I did not find a solution for $15\le k\le 32$ larger than those in the table. There are no larger solutions upto $n=10^8$ , for $k=15$ and $k=16$ even upto $10^9$.